# Unexpected behavior of call when inheriting from Function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a class that will inherit from Function, but I am unable to call .call on instances of the class.

For example, suppose I define the constructor:

```
function myFunc() {
    Function.call(this);}
```

I set the prototype of **myFunc** to be that of Function:

```
myFunc.prototype = Function.prototype
```

I create an instance of the new class:

```
var f = new myFunc()
```

I can see that `f.\__proto\__` is `Function.prototype`:

```
f.__proto__ === Function.prototype /=> true
```

and that `Function.prototype` has a call method:

```
 Function.prototype.call /=> ƒ call() { [native code] }
```

`nonetheless f.call(null)` returns an error:

```
f.call(null) /=> VM183:1 Uncaught TypeError: f.call is not a function
at <anonymous>:1:3
```

What's going on here?

I thought that `f.call` would check `f.\__proto\__` for a call method, but this doesn't seem to be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does not simply extending built-in classes, at least not historically.

The ability to properly extend built-in classes is an ES6 feature, which typically relies on using ES6 syntax.

```
class MyClass extends SomeBuiltin {}
```

ES5 syntax doesn't really work here, it results in objects that don't properly implement the internal stuff, and ultimately fail on methods and such that require it (giving you that seemingly wrong call method error).

If extending Function is supported by your JavaScript environment, this would work:

```js
class myFunc extends Function {
    constructor() {
        super('return [...arguments]');
    }
}

const f = new myFunc();
console.log(f.call(null, 1, 2, 3)); // [1, 2, 3]
```

I'd tend to recommend not extending `Function` in the first place though, because it requires code evaluation from a string, which is unpleasant, potentially dangerous, and generally unnecessary.